# Return nodes in array of objects on onChange using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code where I print an element of nested list. Every list element has child nodes named `id`, `name` and `ancestors` where `ancestors` containing names and id's of its parent node, grandparent node and so on, its ancestors that is in the form of an array. For example:

```
    {
        "name": "Child",
        "id": "3",
        "ancestors": [{
            "name": "Father",
            "id": "2"
        }, {
            "name": "Grandfather",
            "id": "1"
        }]
    }
```

And here's the code:

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={this.props.name}
          id={this.props.id}
          ancestors={this.props.ancestors}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        {this.props.name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to print this list and every time an element is clicked on, I need to send the `ancestor id's` of the clicked element as an array back to the `Parent` component, the caller. I am able to send the `id` of the list element back to the `Parent` component but I don't know how to access the `id's` of `ancestors` node and return as an array since `ancestors` is itself an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` method on `ancestors` property and return array of ids.

```js
var props = {
  "name": "Child",
  "id": "3",
  "ancestors": [{
    "name": "Father",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "Grandfather",
    "id": "1"
  }]
}

var ancestors = props.ancestors.map(({id}) => id);
console.log(ancestors)
```

So your react code can look something like this.

```js
let {Component} = React;

var data = {"name":"Child","id":"3","ancestors":[{"name":"Father","id":"2"},{"name":"Grandfather","id":"1"}]}

class Parent extends Component {
  handleInputChange(ancestors) {
    console.log('From parent component:', ancestors)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul><Child onInputChange={this.handleInputChange} {...data} /></ul>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  handleChange = (e, a) => {
    this.props.onInputChange(a.map(({id}) => id))
  }
  
  render() {
    let {name, id, ancestors} = this.props;
    return (
      <li>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={name}
          id={id}
          ancestors={ancestors}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, ancestors)}
        />
        {name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out @Nenad Vracar

Comment: @user8907896 You're welcome, little late response but you could do something like this if you want to pass all props back to parent https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/92289/